# One-Step Ahead Forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

Could someone please confirm for me that the "Example Code" below is a one-step ahead forecast?  The reason I ask is because I'm a little confused by the out-of-sample forecast in the Rob Hyndman blog link below.  If someone could please explain the difference, besides that one uses ets and the other auto.arima, I'd be grateful.

Example Code:

```
library(forecast)
fit<-auto.arima(train)
forecast(fit,h=1)$mean ## One-Step Ahead Forecast
```

Rob Hyndman Blog:

http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/out-of-sample-one-step-forecasts/

```
library(forecast)
fit <- ets(trainingdata)
fit2 <- ets(testdata, model=fit)
onestep <- fitted(fit2)
```

Comment: See `?fitted.Arima` (same help file as `fitted.ets`) and note these are described as h-step forecasts with the default being `h=1`.

Comment: @A.Webb  Thank you for getting back to me.  I read ?fitted.Arima, it sounds like fitted(fit) is the equivalent of forecast(fit, h=1).  Is that correct?  I'm a little confused by the language "h-step in-sample forecast using ARIMA models".  What is meant by "in-sample"?  My understanding of forecasting is you train on one chunk, and then forecast ahead an "h" number of horizons.

Comment: `fitted` gives in-sample fit, and calling that "[in-sample] forecast" is misleading, IMHO. These are not genuine forecasts because they are based on future data that would not be available in a real-world forecasting exercise... So what A. Webb refers to are not forecasts but just fitted values. Meanwhile, `forecast` gives genuine forecasts as long as you do not cheat by supplying a model estimated on future data.